# Integrating 1/x

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

The standard definition of integrating $\frac{1}{x}$ is:

$$
\int  \frac{dx}{ax + b} = \frac {1}{a} \ln |ax + b| + K 
$$

Now, if I'm understanding the "constant factor rule", that is:
$$
\int k \frac{dy}{dx} dx = k\int  \frac{dy}{dx} dx
$$

Then what if we construct a new fraction:

$$
\frac{1}{ax + b} = \frac{1}{a(x + \frac{b}{a})}
$$

Then we integrate, using the "constant factor rule", such that:

$$
\int \frac{dx}{a(x + \frac{b}{a})} = \frac {1}{a} \int \frac{dx}{(x + \frac{b}{a})} =  \frac{1}{a} \ln |x+\frac{b}{a}| + K 
$$

Given that

$$
\frac{1}{a(x + \frac{b}{a})} =\frac{1}{ax + b}
$$

Why is it that their integrals are not equal?

$$
\frac{1}{a} \ln |x+\frac{b}{a}| + K  = \int \frac{dx}{a(x + \frac{b}{a})} \neq \int  \frac{dx}{ax + b} =  \frac {1}{a} \ln |ax + b| + K 
$$

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something super obvious here, I just don't know what.

Comment: $K' = K+{1\over a}\ln|a|$ verifies that the two functions differ by a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But they are equal:

$$\ln|ax + b| = \ln\Big(|a| |x + \frac b a|\Big) = \ln |a| + \ln |x + \frac b a|$$

Now just roll $\ln |a|$ into the arbitrary constant.

Comment: A useless edit: they* (?)

Comment: @Miguelgondu Done, thanks.

Comment: Ah. Now I have another question I just realised I've never asked: can I just drop all our constant terms in our indefinite integral?

Comment: No. The integral of a constant is a linear function, so it doesn't disappear.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the constant term in the result of the indefinite integral. So in this case, $\ln |{a}|$

Comment: Yes, you can just write it as a part of the big constant you end up with; if you have a case where you need to find the constant (e.g. solving a differential equation), it might be convenient not to.

Comment: You should also note that there can be different constants of integration, either side of $-\frac{b}{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Like T. Bongers said, they are equal. Your two constants, however, are not. When comparing different setups of the same integral, I highly suggest setting different names for your final constants so you won't forget that the first $K$ is actually the second $K$ plus $\ln |a|$.